# how to use primary category in my wordpress woocommerce site as a breadcrumb?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, categories

In my WooCommerce site breadcrumb issue available. when I select more than one category and mark one as a primary but its not work on breadcrumb. My question is how to show primary category in breadcrumb in my WooCommerce site?